# Image Sequence Showing up as missing

Tags: animation, texturing, image

I am not understanding why my image sequence is showing up as missing images when my files names are unique like this: DarkAndScaryZombie

[image]

But when they are named like this: File 1, 2, 3... the images appear. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "file names are unique"? As I understand it a sequence of files in Blender, both for the VSE and image frame sequence, has to be the same name with the sequence number on the end, i.e: "DarkAndScaryZombie.001.jpg", "DarkAndScaryZombie.002.jpg" etc. The list displayed in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bq3RiZvqXMg&) tutorial seems to confirm that.

Comment: @JohnEason unique in the sense that they are not the same name or sequentially numbered. This seems to be a requirement for the image sequence node to work and perhaps this is something I have not realized until now. 
when it comes to using image sequence, is it possible to include images with unique names?

Comment: @JohnEason Or a way to formate a filename to tell Blender these images are all part of the sequence? ... I've tried affixing something standard to the beginning of the filename like "Frame_...". These filenames are now something like, Frame_DarkAndScaryZombie, Frame_LightAndFriendlyZombie, Frame_MediumZombie.... etc. I've also included a file number at the end (1,2,3) but that doesn't work either. Docs say  the images must contain a digit to indicate the frame order. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/image_formats.html#image-formats-open-sequence

Comment: They all have to have the same filename with an appended sequence number at the end as far as I know.

Comment: @JohnEason Hmm, well in that case the documentation should be updated or clarified

Comment: Blender has to know what order they need to be loaded. However I have to say that it's not at all clear that they all have to have the same initial name. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/image_formats.html#opening-an-image-sequence) is the section in the Blender manual.

Comment: To be more accurate, and this is true for almost EVERY file sequence naming convention, a single sequence of files needs to have a unique name and a (often zero padded) frame number suffix. This does two things: the unique name makes sure you are not mixing up different sequences that would happen to be in the same folder, and the frame number indicates the order of frames (and some software also need them to start from either 0 or 1, some support any positive start number).

Comment: Different names, with or without frame numbers, are considered to be different sequences. You can use just frame numbers, but do expect unexpected behaviors if you have multiple sequences in the same folder with just frame number as names.